# regex for replacement of specific character outside parenthesis only

Tags: r, regex, gsub, string-substitution

I am looking for regex (preferably in `R`) which can replace (any number of) specific characters say `;` with say `;;` but only when **not present** inside parenthesis `()` inside the text string.

**Note: 1. There may be more than one replacement character present inside parenthesis too**

**2. There are no nested parenthesis in the data/vector**

Example

- `text;othertext` to be replaced with `text;;othertext`
- but `text;other(texttt;some;someother);more` to be replaced with `text;;other(texttt;some;someother);;more`.  *(i.e. `;` only outside `()` to be replaced with replacement text)*

Still if some clarification is needed I will try to explain

```r
in_vec <- c("abcd;ghi;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);dfg;(asd;fdsg);ag", "zvc;dfasdf;asdga;asd(asd;hsfd)", "adsg;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);sdafdf", "asagf;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;sdfa")

in_vec
#> [1] "abcd;ghi;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);dfg;(asd;fdsg);ag"
#> [2] "zvc;dfasdf;asdga;asd(asd;hsfd)"             
#> [3] "adsg;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);sdafdf"           
#> [4] "asagf;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;sdfa"
```

Expected output (calculated manually)

```
[1] "abcd;;ghi;;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);;dfg;;(asd;fdsg);;ag" 
[2] "zvc;;dfasdf;;asdga;;asd(asd;hsfd)"             
[3] "adsg;;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);;sdafdf"            
[4] "asagf;;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa"
```

Comment: Please tell if any clarification is needed

Comment: Adding some code that you've tried might help make the process you're thinking of more clear

Comment: @camille, sure I will add all my trials soon :)

Comment: I also wonder whether there's a solution to this upstream—does the text have to be formatted this way to begin with? Or is it a situation you have no control over?

Comment: What about nested `(`? What should the output be of, say, `"asagf;(fafgf;(sadg);sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;sdfa"`?

Comment: @nicola, there are no nested parenthesis in the data/vector.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Great, I think you should add this info to the question, since it's very relevant for building a solution (would have been much harder with nested parenthesis).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with `;(?![^(]*\\))`:

```
gsub(";(?![^(]*\\))", ";;", in_vec, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "abcd;;ghi;;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);;dfg;;(asd;fdsg);;ag"
#[2] "zvc;;dfasdf;;asdga;;asd(asd;hsfd)"                   
#[3] "adsg;;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);;sdafdf"                  
#[4] "asagf;;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa"
```

`;` finds `;`, `(?!)` .. Negative Lookahead (make the replacement when it does not match), `[^(]` .. everything but not `(`, `*` repeat the previous 0 to n times, `\\)` .. flowed by `)`.

Or

```
gsub(";(?=[^)]*($|\\())", ";;", in_vec, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "abcd;;ghi;;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);;dfg;;(asd;fdsg);;ag"
#[2] "zvc;;dfasdf;;asdga;;asd(asd;hsfd)"                   
#[3] "adsg;;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);;sdafdf"                  
#[4] "asagf;;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa"
```

`;` finds `;`, `(?=)` .. Positive Lookahead (make the replacement when it does match), `[^)]` .. everything but not `)`, `*` repeat the previous 0 to n times, `($|\\()` .. match end `$` or `(`.

Or using `gregexpr` and `regmatches` extracting the part between `(` and `)` and making the replacement in the non-matched substrings:

```
x <- gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", in_vec)  #Find the part between ( and )
mapply(function(a, b) {
  paste(matrix(c(gsub(";", ";;", b), a, ""), 2, byrow=TRUE), collapse = "")
}, regmatches(in_vec, x), regmatches(in_vec, x, TRUE))
#[1] "abcd;;ghi;;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);;dfg;;(asd;fdsg);;ag"
#[2] "zvc;;dfasdf;;asdga;;asd(asd;hsfd)"                   
#[3] "adsg;;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);;sdafdf"                  
#[4] "asagf;;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa"
```

But all of them will work only for simple open `(` close `)` combinations.

Comment: thanks for a solution. +1 already.  The requirement is like that only (open and close combination).  But isn't any regex possible for matching specific characters outside this combination?

Comment: Yes, as the numbers of characters (to be replaced) before and after `( or )` are not certain

Comment: Works like a charm.  Wish I could upvoted you twice. :) accepting this.  Meanwhile can you please explain a bit about your regex?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if the input contains nested parenthesis? For instance, say you have `asagf;(fafgf;(sadg);sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;sdfa` and the desired output is `asagf;;(fafgf;(sadg);sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa` (your solution doubles the first `;` inside the outer `(`).

Comment: @nicola Maybe ask a new question with this topic. When you change `x <- gregexpr("\\(.*?\\)", in_vec)` to `x <- gregexpr("(\\(([^()]|(?R))*\\))", in_vec, perl=TRUE)` it might work for nested parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

Though the problem can be tackled with regex, using a simple function might be more straightforward and easier to understand.

```r
replace_semicolons_outside_parentheses <- function(raw_string) {
    """Replace ; with ;; outside of parentheses"""

    processed_string <- ""
    n_open_parentheses <- 0

    # Loops over characters in raw_string
    for (char in strsplit(raw_string, "")[[1]]) {

        # Update the net number of open parentheses
        if (char == "(") {
            n_open_parentheses <- n_open_parentheses + 1
        } else if (char == ")") {
            n_open_parentheses <- n_open_parentheses - 1
        }

        # Replace ; with ;; outside of parentheses
        if (char == ";" && n_open_parentheses == 0) {
            processed_string <- paste0(processed_string, ";;")
        } else {
            processed_string <- paste0(processed_string, char)
        }      
    }
    return(processed_string)
}
```

Note that the function above also works for nested parentheses: no semicolons inside nested parentheses are replaced! The desired output can be obtained in a single line:

```r
out_vec <- lapply(in_vec, replace_semicolons_outside_parentheses)

# 1. 'abcd;;ghi;;dfsF(adffg;adfsasdf);;dfg;;(asd;fdsg);;ag'
# 2. 'zvc;;dfasdf;;asdga;;asd(asd;hsfd)'
# 3. 'adsg;;(asdg;ASF;DFG;ASDF;);;sdafdf'
# 4. 'asagf;;(fafgf;sadg;sdag;a;gddfg;fd)gsfg;;sdfa'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following  in case of no nested parentheses:

```r
gsub("\\([^()]*\\)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;", ";;", in_vec, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/eeqzUN/2).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '(' char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]*                   any character except: '(', ')' (0 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \)                       ')' char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)           skip current match, search for new one from here
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                        ';'
```

If there are nested parentheses:

```
gsub("(\\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|;", ";;", in_vec, perl=TRUE)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/eeqzUN/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^()]++                  any character except: '(', ')' (1 or more times 
                               (matching the most amount possible, no backtracking))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                         or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     (?1)                    recursing first group pattern
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                         ')' 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  )                          end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
  (*SKIP)(*FAIL)             skip the match, search for next
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  |                         or
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ;                         ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```