# in r and regex, how to detect a character with excluding some mixed condition

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to detect some dots (.) in my string and replace them with the same dots alongside a word, for example "." becomes ".AAA" . but there are some conditions that I want to avoid replacing:

1. if there is a space and then a single character before the dot
2. if the dots are between two hyphens (-)

for example, if the input is:

```
string <- "first. - second. - third. 4."
```

my desired output is:

```
"first.AAA - second. - third.AAA 4."
```

for the first condition I could figure out this:

```
str_replace_all("[^ [A-Z19a-z]\\.]([\\.])","\\1AAA")
```

but got confused when reading about look-ahead and look-behind for solving the second condition and mixing the two together.

Comment: What kind of single character do you mean? Any non-whitespace char? Or any char including line break chars? Or an alphanumeric only?

Comment: I dont get why the . after "second" is not replaced.  it doesnt look like it meets your two conditions

Comment: @Eric Because it is between two hyphens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by a  single character you mean any char including line break chars, you can use

```r
gsub("(?s)(?:\\s.\\.|-[^-]*-)(*SKIP)(?!)|(\\.)", "\\1AAA", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7OmM62/1). If you need to precise that "any char" condition replace the unescaped dot in `\\s.\\.` with the appropriate construct.

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - a dotall `s` flag that makes the dot match any chars incluing line break chars
- `(?:\s.\.|-[^-]*-)` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `\s.\.` - a whitespace, **any one char**, a dot
  - `|` - or
  - `-[^-]*-` - a hyphen, zero or more chars other than a hyphen and then a hyphen
- `(*SKIP)(?!)` - skip the match failing it at the current location and triggering the search for the next match from the failure position
- `|` - or
- `(\.)` - Group 1: a dot.

Comment: wow that is a comprehensive answer and the result as shown in regex demo is exactly what I need. but I don't know why when I run it on my pc (Rstudio) I just get "\\1AAA" as answer. any idea?

Comment: @mohsen0965 I am not sure where exactly you are using this regex. It works as expected in the `gsub` function I supplied. If there is a problem *outside of the gsub` command* with the replacement pattern try replacing ``\\1`` with `$1. However, you need a PCRE regex engine to use this regex pattern.

Comment: Ah I got it. I was using pipe and had not used x=. in the code. Thanks a lot